# Does it matter which branch I push to?

Tags: git, branching, push

My question is around how branch pushes work exactly; I have come across something that doesn't make logical sense to me and as such would like an explanation as to why I am experiencing this behaviour.

I have two branches: `master` and `dashboard`.

I am on (checked out) `dashboard`.  I make some changes on it and (using the terminal) I type the following:

```
git add file1.R
git commit -m "Updated loop."
git push origin dashboard
```

My understanding is that this now pushes the committed changes into my repository under the `dashboard` branch.

However, out of curiosity I also tried this (whilst still checked out on `dashboard`:

```
git add file1.R
git commit -m "Updated loop."
git push origin master
```

Despite specifying that I want to push to `master`, the committed changes still appear to have been pushed to `dashboard` because when I check `master` (both via a GUI and `git log -1`), I see that the changes haven't been pushed to `master`, but rather to `dashboard`.

As such, what is the relevance of specifying which branch to push to?  The reason I ask is because it appears that the branch that the committed changes are pushed to correspond with whichever branch I currently have checked out / am pushing from.

Would `git push` be the same as typing `git push origin master`/`git push origin dashboard` (depending on which branch I have checked out)?

It would be great to understand precisely what is happening here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have glossed over some stuff to stay straight-forward. Check `man git` or `git help` for the nitty-gritty.

`git push` on its own says "push my current branch to its corresponding upstream branch".

`git push origin xyz` says "push my `xyz` branch to its corresponding branch in `origin`". It does *not* say "push my current branch to `origin`'s `xyz`, though that's a very easy assumption to make.

To do what you thought you were doing, use something like `git push origin dashboard:master` ("push my `dashboard` branch to `master` in `origin`"). This is safe in the sense that it will only work if the branch you are pushing is up-to-date with the branch you are pushing *to*, so that you will not lose history.

`git push` is quite flexible (again, see the manual for details), but the pertinent parts can be summarized as:

```
git push [remote [source][:destination]]
```

That is, if you specify a remote (such as `origin`) you can specify a source (local) to push from, and a destination branch (on the remote) to push to.

- With neither source nor destination, it will push the current branch to its corresponding upstream branch.
- With only a source, it will push *that* branch to its corresponding upstream branch.
- With only a destination, it will push "nothing" to that branch - which means deleting it on the remote.
- With both, you can push a local branch to one which is not its default corresponding one.
- Source does not have to be a branch - it can be `HEAD` ("current branch"), `master~1` ("previous commit on `master`), etc..

Comment: So according to your explanation (and also my experience/expectation) MusTheDataGuy simply made a wrong observation?

Comment: @gillesB I can only guess, but it looks like the file was already comitted and pushed to dashboard when Mus started experimenting. Personally I usually gloss over git's feedback messages unless they are longer than one line, so it would be easy to miss, for example, "No staged changes" and "Everything up to date" when adding an unchanged file, comitting an unchanged index, and pushing an unchanged branch.